# SED not working with -i and -E together

Tags: bash, shell, sed

This file would be a `httpd.conf`:

```
some_config_1
some_config_2
CustomLog /app-test.log combined
ErrorLog /error-test.log
some_config_5
some_config_6
some_config_7
```

If I run:

`sed -E "s|(CustomLog ).*|\1${LOG_PATH} combined|" httpd.conf`

[...] it prints exactly what I want, but if I run with `-i`:

`sed -iE "s|(CustomLog ).*|\1${LOG_PATH} combined|" httpd.conf`

[...] I get this error:

`sed: 1: "s|(CustomLog ).*|\1/app ...": \1 not defined in the RE`

If I scape the parenthesis it works, but the `-E` is to avoid doing this for RegEx and there's a few other samples that don't work either.

In my use case, I need to update this file, so I need to use the `-i` option.

Note: Although not spread, `-E` works as `-r` on Linux, AFAIK.

Anybody has any idea of what is happening here?

I'm on MacOS 10.12.4.

Comment: `sed -iE` tells sed to use `E` as the backup suffix.  Use `sed -i -E ...`

Comment: @WilliamPursell Got exactly the same problem.

Comment: @JourdanRodrigues in addition to separation, you might need to pass empty argument... like `sed -i'' -E ` or if that doesn't work, `sed -i.bak -E `

Comment: @Sundeep Since I was already performing a manual backup, your solution was perfect: `sed -i.backup -E ...`. You should give an answer for it. :)